# missing : after property id in twig

Tags: php, javascript, symfony, twig

I'm a new developer in Symfony2 so I'm suffering to convert an array of objects which I get from the controller in an array with JavaScript in my twig.

The problem is that I have an array of an array:

here an example

```
 $Flight = array
                (
                '1' => array
                    (
                    '5' => array
                        (
                        'LFID' => '6684',
                        'DepartureDate' => '2012-10-22T12:30:00',
                        'ArrivalDate' => '2012-10-22T14:00:00',
                        'BaseFareAmtInclTax' => '343.50',
                        'ReturnFlightSegmentDetails' =>
                        
                    ),
                    '10' => array
                        (
                        'LFID' => '6684',
                        'DepartureDate' => '2012-10-23T12:30:00',
                        'ArrivalDate' => '2012-10-23T14:00:00',
                        'BaseFareAmtInclTax' => '243.50',
                        'ReturnFlightSegmentDetails' =>
                        array
                            (
                            '150' => array
                                (
                                'LFID' => '6647',
                                'DepartureDate' => '2012-10-24T12:25:00',
                                'FareTypeName' => 'Change',
                                'FareTypeID' => '22',
                                'BaseFareAmtInclTax' => '198',
                            )
                            
                        )
                    )
                ),
            );
```

in the twig I'm doing:

```
{% for flight in flights%}
                   var $FlightSegment = new Array();
                  $flight.push({
                        DepartureDate:"{{flight.DepartureDate}}",
                        ArrivalDate:"{{flight.ArrivalDate}}",
                        Amount:"{{flight.BaseFareAmtInclTax}}",
                        {% for ReturnFlightSegmentDetails in flight.ReturnFlightSegmentDetails %}
                          $FlightSegment.push({
                                ReturnFlightSegmentDetails :"{{ReturnFlightSegmentDetails.DepartureDate}}",   
                           });
                        {% endfor %}
                        
                    });
                
                
                {% endfor %}
```

but the line " $FlightSegment.push" generate an error which is

> missing : after property id

Comment: Your code as written re-declares "$FlightSegment" for each flight. It then does that inner `.push()` call *inside* the object literal you're building for the outer `.push()` call.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier get the array in the format you want in php then echo it out as json:

```
{% autoescape false %}
    var jsflights = {{ phpflights|json_encode() }};
{% endautoescape %}
```

In the example above I assume a variable $phpflights, is a php array in the format you want that you have passed to the view. 
The code above is in the view and creates a javascript array jsflights with the same structure as the php array.

This way you don't need to write the array code twice.

Comment: Thanks so much for ur answer i'm grateful ^^ , so to manipulate the attribute ReturnFlightSegmentDetails i ll act like having a js array? that's it ?

Comment: Okay !it worked to echo it but if i want to manipulate the elements of the string returned by the json_encode how to parse it  ?! i don't see things clearly :'(

Comment: it will be a javascript array. manipulate it as you would an array.

Comment: But jsflights.length return undefined :/

Comment: I'm not getting out with this approach :/

Answer (score 0):

Your original template code looks like it contains PHP, which isn't allowed in twig templates.

More generally, templates are supposed to be for presenting data and maybe doing minimal reworking on it to aid with that. For what you're doing, it looks like you'd be better off doing it in the controller in PHP and then passing the result, which'll already be prepared for display, to twig.

Comment: i know i understand perfectly what u said but i'm a part of a big project nd my boss would to have some parts done on the client Side so i have to get the php data nd convert it into js so i could manipulate it in a twig file

Comment: Oh, I see what you're doing now. I didn't look closely at the code in the template, so didn't realize it was JS (saw $'s in front of the variables and assumed PHP).